# Sending query string parameters to php via fetch not working

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I simply want to send a query string parameter to a (same page) php script via the fetch api. The purpose is so that I can store a variable that exists in javascript inside a php $_SESSION variable instead. But it's not working.

Background: I wrote some javascript that detected which radio button out of several was toggled on. The value of this radio button stores the name of a PHP template that I wanted to load as an SSI from a database.

So I don't really want to manipulate the response in javascript, I just want to be able to pass the variable (hardcoded in this example, but intended to come from a javascript variable) to PHP $_GET or $_POST.

Thanks to people who have answered so far.

Code below:

```
<?php 

if(isset ($_REQUEST['name'])){
    echo "The name param is received!";
}
else {
    echo "The name param is NOT received!";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

   <script>
 
       fetch('index.php?name=matt');

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fetch` is JS, not PHP. Guessing you tagged this incorrectly? Please describe `not working`, it is unclear what doesn't work.

Comment: `Fetch()` gets the page and returns the result, then within the `.then()` blocks after it, you work with the results it returns.  You don't seem to be doing the second part?  `Fetch()` will not simply load the page URL you input to it for the browser location.

Comment: Do you mean a simple anchor tag? `<a href='?name=matt'>Click Me</a>`

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What are you expecting?

Comment: `fetch('index.php?name=matt');` by itself doesn't do anything useful. You need to write some code to get the response and use it. Seems maybe you need to look at some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So, "not working" means what exactly? How have you debugged it? You say you want to store the value in the Session, but none of your code attempts to do that. And although you're using an `echo` to see if you receive the parameter or not, you'll never see that because your Javascript fetch code doesn't handle the response from the server, which would include the echoed text. You could use the Network inspector in your browser's Developer Tools though to view the raw response from the fetch call to index.php, and see what text is echoed. Have you done that?

Comment: N.B. You will of course always see `The name param is NOT received!` printed when you first load the page, because the initial load of index.php into your browser will not have the "name" parameter set, so it will inevitably print that text. But that's not relevant - it's the second call to index.php (via fetch()) which sends the variable, so it's the response to that call you'd need to look at in order to know if it's working. (Also, often good practice with code designed to receive AJAX requests is to put it in a separate script file so it doesn't get tangled up with your main pages).

Comment: Hi, Matthew: I see you updated your question!  I updated my answer below, if you follow the bold text mid-way through.

Comment: Holy cow! The developer tools (the Preview tab under Network) shows "The name param is received!" and the Response tab shows that line plus the rest of the HTML. BUT the PHP echo statement in the brower still says the same:  "The name param is NOT received." Is this weird, or is that the expected outcome? Strange mismatch in my eyes. I'm on localhost with XAMPP. Thanks for your suggestion, btw. Oh, just read previous explanation about the order of the execution. I'm so dumb! Thanks.

Comment: "Is this weird"...No. I already explained why it's happening. To emphasise again, you are making **two** separate calls to index.php - one when you load the page, and one when you run the fetch() command. The same PHP code executes in both cases. When you first load the page, the code always falls into the `else` block because the parameter isn't set. That's why I suggest that it's usually a good idea to put code which responds to fetch() requests into a separate script file, then it doesn't get mixed up with your page code and cause unwanted / unexpected behaviour such as you're noticing here

Comment: HoldOffHunger's updated example (with the userdata.php file) in the answer below is a good example of keeping the functionality separate as I've suggested.

Comment: Let me know if my answer was sufficient!  If you mark it as correct, it will help others with the same problem in the future!  thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the [**MDN Fetch() API documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  Your `fetch()` is missing its headers, its method, a response resolution (first `.then()`), and a result resolution (second `.then()`).

But, you MIGHT NOT WANT to use `fetch()`.  Fetch returns the result of the page to the JavaScript, not to the user.  The way you're using it, it looks like you just want the user to go to that page directly (in which case, just `<a href='?name=matt'>Click Me</a>`).

Ultimately, *I think you need to understand that the purpose of `fetch()` is to send data to the JS environment, not to reload the page for the user.* Anyway, here's how your call would look if it worked...

```
<script>
       fetch('index.php?name=matt', {
        'headers': {
            'Accept': 'text/html',
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        },
        'method':'GET',
        'body':'',
    })
   .then((response) => response.text())
   .then((responseText)=>{
       console.info("Response?");
       console.info(responseText);     // result: "The name param is received!...(and the rest of your page)
   });
</script>
```

***If you wanted to have fetch() return `$_GET` and/or `$_POST` variables to the JS in a usable fashion, then welcome JSON and `json_encode()` into your heart.***

Make a new PHP script, `userdata.php`, and code it as so...

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   // send JSON header, let page know it's JSON
    print(json_encode(['name':$_POST['name']]));    // get the name
?>
```

With this, update your above JS to be...

```
fetch('http://www.example.com/your/script.php', {
    'headers': {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    'method':'POST',
    'body':JSON.stringify({'name':'matt'}),
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson)=>{
    console.info("Response?");
    console.info(responseJson);
});
```

Notice what I have changed above: I made it use the POST method, which gives you a cleaner way of sending the data (namely using `body`, instead of appending it onto the URL, like `'?...'`).  Your response, also, is `.json()`'d, and not `.text()`d.

Comment: The plot thickens; check their edit. Great answer though.

Comment: Updated!  Had to dig out some old code.