# how to use react js for front-end and php for back-end

Tags: php, reactjs

I had built a PHP back-end and I just want to make a simple interface for it using react js and I am using CLI script for running the PHP so I am not using any framework just PHP so this is the PHP file that I build and just I want to know how to connect PHP back-end to react js if you can help me with it or give me some link to follow it.

```
<?PHP

/**
* The interface provides the contract for different readers
* E.g. it can be XML/JSON Remote Endpoint, or CSV/JSON/XML local files
*/
interface ReaderInterface
{
/**
* Read in incoming data and parse to objects
*/
public function read(string $input): OfferCollectionInterface;
}

 /**
 * Interface of Data Transfer Object, that represents external JSON data
 */
interface OfferInterface
{
}

/**
* Interface for The Collection class that contains Offers
*/
interface OfferCollectionInterface
{
public function get(int $index): OfferInterface;
public function getIterator(): Iterator;
}

/* *********************************** */

class Offer implements OfferInterface
{
public $offerId;
public $productTitle;
public $vendorId;
public $price;


public function __toString(): string
{
    return "$this->offerId | $this->productTitle | $this->vendorId | $this->price\n";
 }
}   

class OfferCollection implements OfferCollectionInterface
{
private $offersList = array();

public function __construct($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $json_object) {
        $offer = new Offer();
        $offer->offerId = $json_object->offerId;
        $offer->productTitle = $json_object->productTitle;
        $offer->vendorId = $json_object->vendorId;
        $offer->price = $json_object->price;

        array_push($this->offersList, $offer);
    }
}

public function get(int $index): OfferInterface
{
    return $this->offersList[$index];
}

public function getIterator(): Iterator
{
    return new ArrayIterator($this->offersList);
}

public function __toString(): string
{
    return implode("\n", $this->offersList);
}
}

class Reader implements ReaderInterface
{
/**
* Read in incoming data and parse to objects
*/
public function read(string $input): OfferCollectionInterface
{
    if ($input != null) {
        $content = file_get_contents($input);
        $json = json_decode($content);
        $result = new OfferCollection($json);

        return $result;
    }

    return new OfferCollection(null);
}
}

class Logger {
private $filename = "logs.txt";

public function info($message): void {
    $this->log($message, "INFO");
}

public function error($message): void {
    $this->log($message, "ERROR");
}

private function log($message, $type): void {
    $myfile = fopen($this->filename, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "[$type] $message\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
}

$json_url = 'data.json';

$json_reader = new Reader();
$offers_list = $json_reader->read($json_url);


function count_by_price_range($price_from, $price_to)
{
global $offers_list;
$count = 0;
foreach ($offers_list->getIterator() as $offer) {
    if ($offer->price >= $price_from && $offer->price <= $price_to) {
        $count++;
    }
}
return $count;
}

function count_by_vendor_id($vendorId)
{
global $offers_list;
$count = 0;
foreach ($offers_list->getIterator() as $offer) {
    if ($offer->vendorId == $vendorId) {
        $count++;
    }
}
return $count;
}

$cli_args = $_SERVER['argv'];

$function_name = $cli_args[1];
$logger = new Logger();

switch ($function_name) {
case "count_by_price_range": {
    $logger->info("Getting Count By Price Range From: $cli_args[2] TO $cli_args[3]");
    echo count_by_price_range($cli_args[2], $cli_args[3]);
    break;
}
case "count_by_vendor_id": {
    $logger->info("Getting Count By vendor Id: $cli_args[2]");
    echo count_by_vendor_id($cli_args[2]);
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Here's an answer I have to a similar question, [Sending query string parameters to php via fetch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708531/2430549), cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs is frontend and PHP is backend, you can connect between React App and PHP services by REST API